# algebraic multiplicity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$, $S \in L(V)$ and $S$ is invertible. Here $L$ is the space of all linear operators on $V$. 
How to prove that $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$ has the same eigenvalues, with the same multiplies?

My thoughts so far:

The first part is clear, since if $Tv = \lambda v$, then $S^{-1}TS(S^{-1}v) = S^{-1}Tv = \lambda S^{-1}v$

i.e. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $S^{-1}v$ the eigenvector.

For the second part, I need to show

$$ \dim null(S^{-1}TS - \lambda I)^{\dim{V}} = \dim null(T - \lambda I)^{\dim{V}}  $$

Because that's the definition of algebraic multiplicity.

I'm tempted to think that $S^{-1}$ is an isomorphism between the two null spaces, thus finishing the proof. But I'm not sure how to continue here.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not far off. This may help: $$S^{-1} T S - \lambda I = S^{-1}(T - \lambda I)S$$

Comment: @TheoBendit so $(S^{-1}TS-\lambda I)^{\dim{V}}v = 0$ iff  $(T-\lambda I)^{\dim{V}} S^{\dim{V}}v = 0$, therefore $S^{\dim{V}}$ is the isomorphism I want. Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I forgot to put powers into my hint. Remember, it can be the case that $(ST)^n \neq S^n T^n$, due to the fact that operators need not commute (like the matrices they correspond to). But, it is true that $$(S^{-1}TS)^n = S^{-1}TSS^{-1}TSS^{-1}T\ldots SS^{-1}TS = S^{-1}T^nS.$$ The operator you want is just $S$.